# Select closest maximal numeric value in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

Imagine there're 2 tables, let's call them "Master" and "Detail":

```
Master
--------------------------------
| ID | field_1 | ... | field_n |
--------------------------------
```

```
Detail
--------------------------------------------
| ID | master_id | f_value | ... | field_n |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |      1    |   0.03  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 2  |      1    |   0.95  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 3  |      1    |   1.22  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 4  |      2    |   0.91  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 5  |      2    |   0.93  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 6  |      2    |   2.07  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
```

There're 2 input parameters: list of Master IDs (`master_id_list`) and numeric value (`num_value`).

For every `ID` in `master_id_list` I should get one Detail record:

1. If `num_value < MIN( f_value )`, it should be the record with `MIN( f_value )`
2. If `num_value > MAX( f_value )`, it should be the record with `MAX( f_value )`
3. Otherwise it should be the record with the closest **maximal** `f_value`

Example1. `master_id_list = [ 1, 2 ]`, `num_value = 0`. Result:

```
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |      1    |   0.03  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 4  |      2    |   0.91  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Example2. `master_id_list = [ 1, 2 ]`, `num_value = 50`. Result:

```
--------------------------------------------
| 3  |      1    |   1.22  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 6  |      2    |   2.07  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Example3. `master_id_list = [ 1, 2 ]`, `num_value = 0.94`. Result:

```
--------------------------------------------
| 2  |      1    |   0.95  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
| 6  |      2    |   2.07  | ... |   ...   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible with one single SQL query? I've tried to "play" with solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495680/max-nearest-values-sql) but failed.

Comment: I'm confused.  Nothing is called `num_value` in your sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, ```num_value``` is the input parameter for ```f_value```. If ```num_value``` lies between ```MIN( f_value )``` and ```MAX( f_value )```, I need to find the first ```f_value >= num_value```. Otherwise I need to get either ```MIN( f_value )``` or ```MAX( f_value )```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call `num_value` your needle (as in, "needle in the haystack") that you're looking for.

First we'll normalize the needle so that it is no lower than the `MIN(f_value)` and no higher than the `MAX(f_value)` for each `master_id`.

Then we'll look for each `Detail` row with the nearest `f_value`  that's greater than or equal to our normalized needle, grouped by `master_id`.  (This is then just a [greatest-n-per-group sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql) problem).

```
WITH normalized AS (     -- First normalize the needle for each master_id
  SELECT hilo.master_id,
         MAXVALUE(hilo.lo, MINVALUE(hilo.hi, d.needle)) AS needle
    FROM (SELECT ? FROM rdb$database) d (needle) -- <- change this ? to your needle
         CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT master_id, MAX(f_value), MIN(f_value)
            FROM detail GROUP BY master_id) hilo (master_id, hi, lo)
),
     ranked AS (         -- Next order f_value >= needle by master_id
  SELECT detail.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY detail.master_id ORDER BY f_value ASC)
           AS rk
    FROM detail
         LEFT JOIN
         normalized ON detail.master_id = normalized.master_id
   WHERE detail.f_value >= normalized.needle
)
                         -- Strip off the rank ordering and SELECT what you want
SELECT id, master_id, f_value, ...
  FROM ranked
 WHERE rk = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. But now I wonder: is that stuff with ```rdb$database``` necessary. I've replaced it with
```SELECT "hilo"."master_id", MAXVALUE( "hilo"."lo", MINVALUE( "hilo"."hi", :needle ) ) AS "needle"
FROM (
  SELECT "master_id", MIN( "q_nom" ), MAX( "q_nom" )
  FROM "detail"
  GROUP BY "master_id"
) "hilo" ( "master_id", "lo", "hi" )```
and it seems works too.

Comment: @OldSkull, well no one knew about the existence of "q_nom" until your comment.  In any case, don't use this answer, use Gordon Linoff's answer below.

Comment: ```q_nom``` is ```f_value```, they are from test and work tables

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a correlated subquery.  Assuming that `num_value` is in the master table and `f` value is in the detail table:

```
select m.*,
       (select first 1 d.f_value
        from detail d
        where d.master_id = m.master_id
        order by abs(m.num_value - d.f_value)
       )
from master m;
```

EDIT:

If you want a preference for the greater value -- if it exists -- just change the `order by` to:

```
order by (case when d.f_value >= m.num_value then 1 else 2 end),
         abs(d.f_value - m.num_value)
```

Comment: ```order by abs(m.num_value - d.f_value)``` would find closest but not **maximal** closest. E.g. you have ```f_value = [ 0.76, 0.85, 0.93, 1,98, 50.23 ]``` and need to find closest maximal to ```0.94```. The result will be ```0.93``` instead of ```1.98```

Comment: @OldSkull . . . Is that what you mean by "maximal closest"?  I figured it was just a way of saying "closest" with emphasis.  You can use `order by (case when d.f_value >= m.num_value then 1 else 2 end), abs(m.num_value - d.f_value) asc`.  This is still much simpler that the alternative answer.  I don't interpret "maximal" as being greater than a particular value, so I misinterpreted that part of the question.

Comment: Thank you. It indeed looks simpler. Sorry for stupid question: how can I get full row (d.*), not only ```f_value```?

Comment: @OldSkull . . . The simplest method is to `JOIN` back to the `details` table.

Comment: thank you. I've finally managed to create working sql. Not sure about its ideological correctness, but it seems to work as expected. Would it be right/necessary to add it to my original question?